# Nomination for Rarst to be a Moderator Pro Tem

Tags: discussion, moderation

At this point [@Rarst](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/users/847/rarst) has become probably the most active user on WordPress Answers and has been flagging more questions than anyone else.  I would like StackExchange to consider a nomination of @Rarst to be promoted to a Moderator Pro Tem to recognize his contributions and to give him the authority to do more moderation than he currently has capabilities to do.

Respectfully,

-Mike Schinkel

Comment: I fully agree, so I give an upvote and a comment!

Comment: +1 I've been on the receiving end of his generosity many times.

Comment: Agreed. Rarst rules.

Comment: Rarst and Mike are this sites two biggest assets. Rarst definitely deserves to be promoted.

Comment: Enough, people... I dig the praise (human, guilty), but this is really about giving me moderator trinkets (because I tend to have time to sink in keeping eye on site) and that was clearly resolved as not happening at moment. Move on, go answer some dusty questions or whatever. We will have chance to throw upvotes and praises around in future moderator elections for everyone who wants to actively contribute and without me being singled out and reminded I have no life. ;)

Comment: +1 for Rarst (space filler)

Answer (score 4):

Wordpress has recently started a trend towards impressive growth. Traffic and visits is **up about 100%** over the last 6 weeks. Wow. The Area 51 stats are looking strong, all the pre-requisites are there, and you are on the short-list for a site design (i.e. coming up on graduation, no date set).

We are working on ways to reward exceptional users for awesome contributions; @Rarst certainly seems deserving. But WordPress Stack Exchange moderation is well-staffed for a site this size.

Moderator elections will be coming shortly after graduation. I sincerely hope @Rarst will consider running. He would be (and *is*) a very strong asset to this site. Thank you.

Comment: See, glad you guys had faith in us. Like a fine wine, we just needed some time to age. :)  And thanks for considering; if nothing else my question was as much to recognize him as anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Honored. :)

But not sure it makes sense to hand manage Pro Tem team now, because we will probably be getting long overdue moderator elections that [started to roll out for SE sites](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/stack-exchange-2011-elections-begin/)...

Only I am not sure how/if us being still stuck in beta affects that.

Comment: My guess is they only need to change a setting so that's why I asked.

Comment: The elections are only for the public sites, and "in beta" means we're not "public" yet. And since we're crawling very slowly to those needed 150 users with +200 rep, I don't think we'll get out of beta soon.